# How to initialize javascript at materialize 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm sorry for asking a dumb question. But my knowledge at JS is poor. I don't know how to initialize materialize component using JS, but with jquery it works well. For example i want to use Collapsible component.
http://next.materializecss.com/collapsible.html

```
<ul class="collapsible">
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And for initialization

```
// JS
var elem = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
var instance = new M.Collapsible(elem, options);

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otst3.jpg)

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: i'm using JS for initialization but i got error when i inspect my browser
it said Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined

Comment: You included the library? Where is your script tag?

Comment: my js is in script,js file, and i only wrote the 2 line var for initialization. Did you try what i'am asking @AsthaSrivastava? How is it? is it work?

Comment: Yes, I did. "Uncaught ReferenceError" error triggers when your code is not able to file that script file.

Comment: I've edited my post and provide my SS of code with the JS inline the code. Can you see what caused the error?

Comment: In place of 'option', give 'accordion' and check.

Comment: how can you do that? i replace 'options' with 'accordion' still not working. Told you i really poor at JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script>
     var elem = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
  var instance = new M.Collapsible(elem, {
    // inDuration: 1000,
    // outDuration: 1000
  });
</script>
<body>

<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Check the working codepen here: https://codepen.io/Astha25/pen/OzJpbQ

Comment: Is there a way to initialize all things in materialize?

Comment: @Asthra I've tried that but it doesn't initialize anything. To initialize something (e.g. .collapsible), I have to do it manually/individually for it to work. (Talking about 1.0.0 without jQuery by the way).